# Does session impact performance in asp.net core 2 for complex objects?

Tags: session, asp.net-core-webapi

In asp.net core 2 we need to save complex objects in json string in session.
So will it impact performance of application because for get and set session it requires serialization and deserialization of complex object respectively?